# Intermittent Static / Garbage External Display On Wake and Boot? Picture included

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

Intermittently (relatively frequent) when the MacBook wakes from sleep and it kicks the external displays on, one or all of them may be fuzzy like this.
I have one display in a Thunderbolt port, and the other one is Apple HDMI adapter in the HDMI port.

I've ruled out the adapters being the problem,
I've done a PRAM reset. (even after it booted from PRAM reset it did it at boot up on login screen)

To fix it, I have to unplug and plug it back in and cross my fingers that it doesn't happen again.

Any ideas?

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

[image: Photo of fuzzy monitors]

Comment: Possible duplicate (mine): [External display occasionally shows just noise](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161494/external-display-occasionally-shows-just-noise)

Comment: I have this exact same problem too. Macbook Pro connected to an external monitor via Thunderbolt. Sometimes when it wakes up I get a crackling noise and static/noise displaying on the monitor. It happens for a few seconds and then goes away. Sometimes it happens 3 or 4 times before returning to normal

Comment: Mine never seems to go away unless I unplug and plug back in... Sometimes I have wait a few seconds before plugging it back in or it will happen again.

Comment: I have had this a few times in many years. I my case it was the monitor that gave this behaviour. (Exactly the same Dell monitor as on the picture). Other monitors did not have this issue.

Comment: Does pressing off button on the monitor and back on again work?

Comment: I use a workaround on my setup which is quicker (and less destructive to window positioning) than unplug / replug. Instead, I press ctrl-shift-eject to put the displays to sleep, then wake them up again by pressing shift a few seconds later. Mostly this resolves the issue for me, although sometimes I have to do this twice. Although perhaps I don't have quite the same problem: I'm using a MacBook Pro Mid 2009 with Apple's Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adaptor, and although I see this static on wake intermittently, I can still see the Mac display through it somewhat.

Comment: Had this on the INTERNAL display of a 15" rMBP. It only lasts a moment or so. Try swapping cables.

Comment: Pressing off button sometimes works... it's just intermittent.

Comment: @geoO Same problem on MBPr 15" 2012: occasional grey noise screen upon *internal* screen wake.  When connected to Dell 4k UHD monitor via displayport and this happens it's quite nasty: I get logged out, all apps force quit immediately as if there was a crash, lose my display arrangement, displays go into default mirror mode & settings, Dell UHD resolutions gone  and have to replug / reopen / readjust everything to my liking. Tried swapping to top end Accell DP 1.2 cable: doesn't help.  Still looking for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the Console log you will find that the WindowServer is having a hard time finding the right protocol for your monitor.

Usually that happens when the hardware (cable/converter) connection are not stable, to long or near interference source.

From your picture it does look like your cable is to long and to close to the external monitor screen, and the Apple adapter is pulling its weight on to the plug.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem with Maverick (in clamshell mode) / external monitor (Samsung SyncMaster 2443) when I lock my screen and use my bluetooth mouse or keyboard to wake up the computer.

I was able to fix the problem in 2 ways:

- open the lid, login and unplu, replug the external monitor (pretty annoying)
- when the multicolor static shows, press CTRL+SHIFT+Eject as if to lock the computer again, then wake up the computer again and I now have the normal login screen as normal (not ideal but less disruptive solution).

I hope this helps !